# What does "[0:v:0]pad=(iw*2)+10:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w" do?

Tags: video, encoding

in:
`ffmpeg -i vidyo4_noltr.h264 -i vidyo4_altr.h264 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=(iw*2)+10:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w" output.h264`

What does `"[0:v:0]pad=(iw*2)+10:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w"` mean?

Comment: Seems like a complicated beast : https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description

Comment: Merging the two videos you specified (-i) with a 10 pixels padding (+10) between them, I think.

Comment: Note: this question is not about programming. Probably other sites are much more relevant for such kind of questions (we have few sister sites, e.g. superuser, or about video, but I'm not sure the question is on-topic on that sites). Put a test case, and try it (and with different test cases, and different options).